# Apache Spark 2.0 Model Persistence

Tags: python, apache-spark

According to this post: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/31/apache-spark-2-0-preview-machine-learning-model-persistence.html
Spark 2.0 includes a language independent model serialization.

Does this support the use case of training a model using spark, and serving the model in a non jvm language (like python without jvm backend, as used in pyspark)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the model. They are saying that it is language independent (and not Spark independent), but there are some things to consider:

1. If the model is rather large (like ALS, for instance), you will have many issues using a non distributed program to load it.
2. You should implement by yourself the logic of loading the model in a non Spark program (they say that they store a JSON for metadata and a Parquet file for the data, so you have to read them).

So, as far as you still use Spark, you can actually save the model with a program written in Python and then load and use it with scala or Java, and vice versa. But if you want to use that model in a non-Spark application, you'll have to write some code and it could even be not feasible (see ALS example)...

Answer (score 0):

Deploying spark mllib models and model pipelines in a non spark environment can be solved by using third party libraries like [MLeap](https://github.com/combust/mleap).

MLeap packages your code into binaries that can be deployed outside of spark using MLeap model import. It has good backward compatibility with MLeap, so as you update your spark and MLeap versions, the previous versions of MLeap will still continue to work, as of now, spark doesn't guarantee this over major releases.